# Holograms as a superposition of many individual interference patterns

Tags: optics, laser, interference, diffraction, hologram

I've recently started reading about non-linear optics and holograms. While I do understand the basics of how holograms are made, by superposing the reference waveform on the object waveform over a film and then passing light through it; there is one aspect of holography that I'm unable to wrap my head around.

Every piece of the hologram contains information about the entire object, and thus, a hologram can be broken into many small parts and each of them can be used to reconstruct the original object. This has been explained using a mirror or a window analogy - that each part of a mirror or a window can be used to see the entire object, independent of its size.

However, I'm unable to interpret the mathematical reasoning behind this. How does every point on the hologram contain some information about the entire object ?

My idea is, consider a point source of light. The light from this point source would interfere with the light from another source (coherent) to create an interference pattern on a screen. When you shine some light on an object, every point on that object acts as a point source. Each of these point sources create an interference pattern on some film. A hologram is basically nothing but all these individual interference patters superimposed on each other, to create another interference pattern.

In this sense, once can say that every point on a hologram contain some information about the entire object. Is this analogy correct, and if not why ? Is there a better analogy that can help me understand holograms better, especially the physical intuitions ?

Thanks.